# How am I going to create a view in Oracle SQL that includes cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your help :

Let's assume that we three tables :

1. `Students` : ( STNO PRIMARY KEY, SName )
2. `Courses` : ( CID PRIMARY KEY , CNAME)
3. `Reg Courses` : ( STNO , CID , RDATE)

If I'm going to use the SQL command to build a restricted `DML` view to show all the data from `(Sname , Cname , RDate)` , should I use cursor? and why and if that's ok how the CODE will be in the end .

Comment: Oh im really sorry , its Oracle =) , sorry again .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "a restricted DML view"? What is the problem you are trying to solve? What do you want to do with the view? But to answer the immediate question: you can **not** use a cursor in a view. Cursors can only be used in PL/SQL programs, not in plain SQL queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . The OP may be referring to nested cursors (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions005.htm).  These are allowed in a `SELECT1` statement, but are not permitted in views.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: interesting. I have been working with Oracle for 20 years now and never stumbled over that ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I don't think I have used this feature, but I stumbled across it once upon a time.  I think it is essentially an old-fashioned way of doing lateral joins.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yea i meant that , im sorry i dont whats going on with me .

Comment: i was studying for my exam , and i saw one of the Qs , and its the way thats its there , i tried to type the code but nothing is working .

Comment: And to be honest im Afraid from it , i was reading tons of websites to explain the functions and the procedure and the trigger , but i can understand at all .